# LinkedIn & Google+ UIActivity View Controller Button?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-plus, linkedin-api, uiactivityviewcontroller

I understand that there is a Facebook & Twitter button for the UIActivity View Controller, but I was wandering if there was a service for sharing to Google+ or LinkedIn through the UIActivityViewController?

Comment: You have to create your own application specific `UIActivity` classes that implement integration with Google+, LinkedIn, or any other service you want that isn't provided by `UIKit`.

Answer (score 2):

There is not one for each available in apple provided types, but you can create your own.  You can create an `UIActivity` class and pass it into the `UIActivityViewController` to handle sending data to each of the services you are looking to interactive with:

```
DataItemProvider *dataToShare = [[DataItemProvider alloc] initWithPlaceholderItem:FileTypeToShare];

GooglePlusActivityType *googleActivity = [[GooglePlusActivityType alloc] init];
LinkdInActivityType *linkdinActivity = [[LinkdInActivityType alloc] init];

NSArray *activityTypes = @[googleActivity, linkdinActivity];
NSArray *activityItems = @[dataToShare];

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:activityTypes];

[activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    //Put in your completion handle code here.
}];

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then implement classes for both `GooglePlusActivityType` and `LinkdInActivityType` to handle loading the data to the two sites.