# How can we add google plus in activity view controller

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using the activity view controller to share message to SMS, Facebook, Twitter. Is it possible to add Google+ too. Please let me know how it is possible in `Swift`

Comment: possible duplicate of [LinkedIn & Google+ UIActivity View Controller Button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600082/linkedin-google-uiactivity-view-controller-button)

Comment: see this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600082/linkedin-google-uiactivity-view-controller-button

Answer (score 0):

By default in the iOS 8, we can see a more a button. If you click it, users can see the google pus app if he/she has installed in their phone. User can select from there if they want to send text message via google+ from there.