# Does iOS Sharing sheet recognize all social apps on the device?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

Our team is building an iOS app from which a user can share media content through social apps present on his iPhone. While testing how other apps behave, I observed that not all apps show all the available sharing options.

Specifically, I don't see the following apps in the sharing options:
Kik, WeChat, Reddit, Youtube, GroupMe, Band.

I have all these apps on my device. So expected all these apps to be shown for sharing. Should the base app explicitly handle all the sharing options?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15696782/5362916

Comment: u mean UIDocumentInteractionController ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Only following ActivityTypes are supported by iOS. Of course you can exclude some of these activities if you want to.

1. UIActivityTypePostToFacebook
2. UIActivityTypePostToTwitter
3. UIActivityTypePostToWeibo
4. UIActivityTypeMessage
5. UIActivityTypeMail
6. UIActivityTypePrint
7. UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard
8. UIActivityTypeAssignToContact
9. UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll
10. UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList
11. UIActivityTypePostToFlickr
12. UIActivityTypePostToVimeo
13. UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo
14. UIActivityTypeAirDrop

Comment: But there are apps which support sharing to Instagram, Pinterest, FB Messenger, Line to name a few. Are these sharing extensions handled separately by the base apps? I tried searcing in iOS official documentation of UIActivityControlView but it didn't mention any such special handling.

Comment: Yes, its possible you can share on other apps. The above mentioned ActivityTypes are those activities which are provided by default. You can explore UIActivityViewController here http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/. If you want to share something on other apps like IG use UIDocumentInteractionController http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954810/sharing-image-on-instagram-in-ios

Comment: So, just to clarify, these default apps are shown in sharing options without any special handling. But if we want any additional app, that needs to be handled specially (like Instagram in the question you shared). Am I right? I am extremely new to iOS infrastructure. So apologies if I am sounding too naive...

Answer (score 1):

For the app to appear in the share sheet:

- The app needs to implement a sharing extension (not all do)
- The sharing extension must support the type of data that is being shared (text, url, image, video...).
- The user must have selected that sharing extension (by tapping on the "More" button at the end of the list)